# Why am I missing PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, xubuntu

I was trying to list installed packages in newly installed Xubuntu 12.04 with:

```
for d in `echo "${PYTHONPATH}" | tr ':' '\n'`; do ls "${d}"; done
```

but after I got nothing I figured out that I am missing PYTHONPATH.
Then I tried it on my Xubuntu 14.04 and I got the same.
I tried to find out why I am missing this variable, but only changing it is mentioned everywhere.
Thanks

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is something *you* define.

Comment: @PeterWood so it is just up to me if i need it or not and if I define it or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$PYTHONPATH` variable is typically empty unless you define it. You can define the variable for example in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` files.

If you want to see what paths your Python uses, you can get a list of them like this in a script or in the interactive shell:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If you want to retrieve them in a regular shell (e.g. BASH), you can take an advantage of Python's `-c` option:

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
```